# How to Add a new row to a DATAGRIDVIEW in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, datagridview, new-operator, row

How to Add a new row to a DATAGRIDVIEW in ASP.NET....using c# Code ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can't do it directly from code. An easier way is to set up a data source with the rows you require.

```
List<string> myDatasource = new List<string>();
myDataSource.Add("New Row 1");
myDataSource.Add("New Row 2");

dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSource;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Are you using data binding already?

Answer (score 0):

use     DataGridView1.Columns.Add();